# Проблема с отправкой формы на телеграм и почту одновременно

Tags: php, email, форма, sendmail, phpmailer

Здравствуйте изначально был вот такой код для отправки данных с форм на email и он прекрасно работал

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Дальше появилась потребность подключить телеграм и данные с формы отлично приходили с помощью данного кода

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['phone'])){
  $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
  $phoneFieldset = "Телефон: ";
  }
}
if (isset($_POST['theme'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['theme'])){
  $theme = strip_tags($_POST['theme']);
  $themeFieldset = "Тема: ";
  }
}
$token = "435310696:AAF9OfxzRKOmygDQ4uKT08PBrGKH5KHS1gc";
$chat_id = "-219956165";
$arr = array(
  $nameFieldset => $name,
  $phoneFieldset => $phone,
  $themeFieldset => $theme
);
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

} else {
header ("Location: /");
}

?>
```

Но сейчас появилась задача соединить эти 2 разных кода которые разбросаны по 2 php файлам соответственно в 1 php файл. Я сделал это следующим образом

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);


    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
}

$token = "435310696:AAF9OfxzRKOmygDQ4uKT08PBrGKH5KHS1gc";
$chat_id = "-219956165";
$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";


function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$message}","r");
```

Но не работает к большому сожалению(( В чем может быть проблема, что я не так написал? Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Зачем вы свой API token для телеграма здесь постите? :)

Comment: @Dmitry чтобы было более наглядно и легче можно было решить проблему, а то мало ли

Comment: метки должны быть другие: php,жесть, смотреть до конца :)

Comment: @Konstantin Okhotnick здравствуйте, мы можем с вами связаться к примеру в чате?

Comment: @LiEm да,конечно. Только сегодня уже не смогу помочь. Или поздно вечером или уже завтра тогда.

Comment: @LiEm если не трудно можете мне напомнить завтра

Comment: @Konstantin Okhotnick очень трудно для меня, я бы вам заплатил даже если бы у вас была возможность сделать сегодня

Comment: @LiEm ну за оплату Вы погорячились. Полный код у Вас есть где-то ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65961/discussion-between-konstantin-okhotnick-and-liem).